# Split a string storing the indices of every substring

Tags: python, regex, string

There is a cool native `.split()` in python, returning the list of substrings. Is there a native or, at least, not very nasty way to split by multiple delimiters and automatically get substring coordinates? Something like this:

```
"abc? !cde".some_smart_split("!?") -> [("abc", 0, 2), (" ", 4, 4), ("cde", 6, 8)]
```

Of course, I can write some naive code myself. But my use case is much more complicated, it would be great to find something concise.

Comment: There's a pretty good chance that you're dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: No, I actually don't. I have a plain text, some xml structure on it and I have to make other markup over it, that is required to contain absolute positions from the initial text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
>>> import re
>>> [(match.group(0), match.start(), match.end())
     for match in re.finditer(r'[^!?]+', 'abc? !cde')]
[('abc', 0, 3), (' ', 4, 5), ('cde', 6, 9)]
```

- The pattern `[^!?]+` to match characters that is not `!`, `?`.
- used [`re.MatchedObject.group(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) to get the matched string.
- [`re.MatchedObject.start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) and [`re.MatchedObject.end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.end) to get the indices of matched parts.

Comment: Beat me to it :) OP seems not to want the slice indices but the index of the first and last character in the match, though (so `match.end()-1`)...

Comment: Index type doesn't matter, of course. Ideologically that really _was_ the answer :)